# Validate XML with XSD In PHP

Tags: php, xml, validation, xsd

I want to validate multiple xml files with different element names , i use a XSD file but is static , there is any way to make it danymic ?

For example i want in `<xs:element name="root">` the name "" be dynamic.
I use the following as validate.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="root">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="info" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="Email"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="Password"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This as file.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <info>
        <Name>Name1</Name>
        <Email>Email1</Email>
        <Password>PSWD</Password>
    </info>

    <info>
        <Name>Name2</Name>
        <Email>Email2</Email>
        <Password>PSWD</Password>
    </info>
</root>
```

And this as index.php to upload the file

```
if(isset($_POST['buttonImport'])) {


    // Copy the xml file in data folder.
    copy($_FILES['xmlFile']['tmp_name'], 'data/' . $_FILES['xmlFile']['name']);


    // Convert xml file to php string.
    $info = simplexml_load_file('data/' . $_FILES['xmlFile']['name']);


    // Check if xml schema is correct.
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->load('data/' . $_FILES['xmlFile']['name'], LIBXML_NOBLANKS); 
    if (!$xml->schemaValidate("validate.xsd")) {
        echo "WRONG XML SCHEMA";
    } else {
       echo "The xml file is correct";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In principle (as far as the W3C spec is concerned) you could make the top-level `complexType` a named global type, and then invoke validation of the top level element (regardless of its name) against that named type.

The problem is that not all schema processors support this. The Saxon s9api API offers `SchemaValidator.setDocumentElementTypeName()`, but your chosen processor might not have any equivalent.

The other approach would be to generate a schema document dynamically using XSLT.

You could also consider using `xsi:type`. It's a slightly different scenario, but the FpML set of standards for financial documents relies on an `xsi:type` attribute on the outermost element to distinguish different document types, rather than relying on the element name.